# Group repeating JSON key value pairs together in list with Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have read and filtered the data I needed from REST API like so:

```
 [[key,value] for groups in results for group in groups['results'] for key,value in group.items() if key in ['utc_offset','country','city','state','name','link','lat','lon']]
```

My output:

```
[['utc_offset', -14400000],
['country', 'CA'],
['city', 'Toronto'],
['link', 'https://www.meetup.com/slashdot-3/'],
['lon', -79.44000244140625],
['name', 'The Toronto Slashdot Meetup Group'],
['state', 'ON'],
['lat', 43.7599983215332],
['utc_offset', -14400000],
['country', 'CA'],
['city', 'Toronto'],
['link', 'https://www.meetup.com/webcentric/'],
['lon', -79.44000244140625],
['name', 'The Greater Toronto Web Centric Meetup Group'],
['state', 'ON'],
['lat', 43.7599983215332],
['utc_offset', -14400000],
['country', 'CA'],
['city', 'Toronto'],
['link', 'https://www.meetup.com/php-27/'],
['lon', -79.37999725341797],
['name', 'The Toronto PHP Meetup Group'],
['state', 'ON'],
.
.
.
]]
```

What I'm attempting to do is group the repeating keys like so they can be modeled into data objects for Django:

```
[['utc_offset', -14400000],['country', 'CA'],['city', 'Toronto'],['link', 'https://www.meetup.com/slashdot-3/'],['lon', -79.44000244140625],['name', 'The Toronto Slashdot Meetup Group'],['state', 'ON'],['lat', 43.7599983215332]]
```

I've tried this:

```
[zip(range(8),[key,value]) for groups in results for group in groups['results'] for key,value in group.items() if key in ['utc_offset','country','city','state','name','link','lat','lon']]
```

But my output is this:

```
<zip object at 0x00000228D3C2F388>
<zip object at 0x00000228D3C2F388>
<zip object at 0x00000228D3C2F388>
<zip object at 0x00000228D3C2F388>
<zip object at 0x00000228D3C2F388>
<zip object at 0x00000228D3C2F3C8>
<zip object at 0x00000228D3C2F3C8>
<zip object at 0x00000228D3C2F3C8>
<zip object at 0x00000228D3C2F3C8>
<zip object at 0x00000228D3C2F388>
 .
 .
 .
 # twice the amount of the records I already have
```

So this is pretty much not the answer, so any help would be great. Thanks!

**EDIT**
 My desired output would be like so

`[['utc_offset', value],['country',value],['city',value],['link',value],['lon',value],['name',value],['state',value],['lat',value]]`

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific with your desired output? For example, the `link` key has multiple values. How would you like each value processed? Like `['link', 'link 1', 'link 2']`, or as a dict, or as in some other form?

Comment: Hey!! I didn't thinks anyone would get back to me so quickly. Each key-value pair is unique and I am trying to line them up so l can shove them into a database. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Whatever format you can line them up in will be fine with me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this is what you're after (I'm still not 100% sure what you want me to do with each block of results):

```
l = [['utc_offset', -14400000],
['country', 'CA'],
['city', 'Toronto'],
['link', 'https://www.meetup.com/slashdot-3/'],
['lon', -79.44000244140625],
['name', 'The Toronto Slashdot Meetup Group'],
['state', 'ON'],
['lat', 43.7599983215332],
['utc_offset', -14400000],
['country', 'CA'],
['city', 'Toronto'],
['link', 'https://www.meetup.com/webcentric/'],
['lon', -79.44000244140625],
['name', 'The Greater Toronto Web Centric Meetup Group'],
['state', 'ON'],
['lat', 43.7599983215332],
['utc_offset', -14400000],
['country', 'CA'],
['city', 'Toronto'],
['link', 'https://www.meetup.com/php-27/'],
['lon', -79.37999725341797],
['name', 'The Toronto PHP Meetup Group'],
['state', 'ON']]

result = []

tmp = []

for item in l:
    if item[0] == 'lat':
        tmp.append(item)
        result.append(tmp)
        tmp = []
    else:
        tmp.append(item)

print(result)
```

Which results in:

```
[
    [
        ['utc_offset', -14400000], 
        ['country', 'CA'], 
        ['city', 'Toronto'], 
        ['link', 'https://www.meetup.com/slashdot-3/'], 
        ['lon', -79.44000244140625], 
        ['name', 'The Toronto Slashdot Meetup Group'], 
        ['state', 'ON'], 
        ['lat', 43.7599983215332]
    ], 
    [
        ['utc_offset', -14400000], 
        ['country', 'CA'], 
        ['city', 'Toronto'], 
        ['link', 'https://www.meetup.com/webcentric/'], 
        ['lon', -79.44000244140625], 
        ['name', 'The Greater Toronto Web Centric Meetup Group'], 
        ['state', 'ON'], 
        ['lat', 43.7599983215332]
    ]
]
```

Each block of `utc_offset` to `lat` gets put in its own list. If you need it in some other format, let me know.

Comment: Thank U!! I've been doing Python for only a few weeks with decorator, generators, and comprehensions, so this would have NEVER occurred to  me. I'd give you more points, but right now it won't even let me give you +1!